# Get-Counter Command is not working in Powershell Core

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core

I have installed Powershell Core from [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell). but in this PowerShell core **Get-Counter** command is not working.

Is there any way to run **Get-Counter** command in PowerShell Core.

Comment: Get-Counter is a Windows only command. Thus it is not in PowerShell Core but in PowerShell on your Windows machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Get-Counter command is not working on Pre-Built PowerShell of windows, you can add package of your desire command from below URL:

[https://www.powershellgallery.com](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows Compatibility Module for PS Core:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-general-availability-of-the-windows-compatibility-module-1-0-0/

You can install in from PSGallery, `Enable-PSRemoting`, and then run `Invoke-WinCommand {get-counter}` from PS Core.